# Using ActiveMQ's js api, how do I specify a durable topic subscription?

Tags: javascript, activemq-classic, durable-subscription

I am using ActiveMQ's amq.js to subscribe to topics in my client-side js.  I do so via a call like this:

```
amq.addListener( clientID, "topic://topicName", updateListener );
```

... but I would like to specify that this topic subscription be durable.

How do I do that?  I assume that I would add a `?propertyName=propertyValue` query string on the end of the topic name, but I can't find documentation on what the appropriate property name and value would be.

(FYI, I am using ActiveMQ 5.8.0)

Comment: I know that there is some genius out there who knows the answer to this question ... I look forward to hearing from you.  ;o)

Comment: do you find the solution?

Comment: No, I sure didn't.

Comment: do you mean activemq ajax cannot create durable subscriber or just we don't find the solution? I come across your problem since I want to use it on jsp to receive message after jsp reopen

Comment: I'm not sure ... I'll admit that we switched to using the STOMP Over WebSocket library to connect directly to ActiveMQ from the client and we don't seem to have issues with it ... though we're not creating durable topic subscriptions there, either:  http://jmesnil.net/stomp-websocket/doc/

Comment: thank you so much, you are so nice, I will study your sharing and hope to have a nice trip